# Mudar nome do botão

Tags: php

No meu código tenho um botão salvar para cada `option` que eu fiz
e agora preciso que, ao salvar, o nome do botão mude para alterar.
Como devo proceder?

```
código:

    // aqui eu verifico o nome do botão
    if(isset($dados) && ($dados['ecocodigocolecao2']!= '' || $dados['ecocodigocolecao1'] != '')){
    $nomebotao == 'Alterar';
    }else{
    $nomebotao == 'Salvar';
    }
<td>
    <?php echo $db->monta_combo("ecocodigocolecao1", $adesao->listarLivros($disciplina['codigocomponente'],1,""), $podeeditar,  "Selecione...", "", "", "", "500", "N", $padrao_id."_1", "", isset($dados)?trim($dados['ecocodigocolecao1']):'""',"","","onchange=  \"buscarsegundaop(this.value,{$disciplina['codigocomponente']},{$disciplina['codigoetapa']})\"");?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $db->monta_combo("ecocodigocolecao2", $dados2, isset($dados)&& trim($dados['ecocodigocolecao2'])==""?"N":"{$podeeditar}", "Selecione...", "", "", "", "500", "N", $padrao_id."_2", "", isset($dados)?trim($dados['ecocodigocolecao2']):'""');?>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="button" id="salvar" name="salvar" 
    <?php echo $podeeditar=="N"?'disabled="disabled"':''?> onclick="salvarcolecao(
<?php echo $disciplina['codigoetapa']?>,
<?php echo $disciplina['comid']?>,
<?php echo $row['adeid']?>,$(this));" value="$nomebotao"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Acho que a pergunta será para javascript/jquery e não de php.

Comment: O que faz a função salvarcolecao? será ai que deverá mudar o nome

Comment: @TiagoGomes

faz uma requisição ajax, e retorna a mensagem de sucesso ou falha.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode adicionar um novo parâmetro e passar o campo usando o `this`:

HTML:

```
<!-- código omitido -->
<td>
    <input type="button" id="salvar" name="salvar" 
    <?php echo $podeeditar=="N"?'disabled="disabled"':''?> onclick="salvarcolecao(
    <?php echo $disciplina['codigoetapa']?>,
    <?php echo $disciplina['comid']?>,
    <?php echo $row['adeid']?>, this);" value="<?php echo $condicao ? 'salvar' : 'alterar' ?>"/>
</td>
```

JS:

```
function salvarcolecao(codigoetapa,comid,adeid, campo){
    $("#ecocod_"+codigoetapa+"_"+comid+"_2").attr('disabled',false);
    ecocodigocolecao1 = $("#ecocod_"+codigoetapa+"_"+comid+"_1").val();
    ecocodigocolecao2 = $("#ecocod_"+codigoetapa+"_"+comid+"_2").val();
    if (verificarRegras(ecocodigocolecao1,ecocodigocolecao2)){
        //alert(ecocodigocolecao1+"---"+ecocodigocolecao2+'=-===='+"#"+codigoetapa+"_"+comid+"_1");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pddeinterativo2015.php?modulo=principal/escolha/principalEscolha&acao=A&aba=Escolha",
            data: "action=salvarEscolha&ecocodigocolecao1="+ecocodigocolecao1+'&ecocodigocolecao2='+ecocodigocolecao2+'&comid='+comid+'&adeid='+adeid,
            async: false,
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);

                // alterando o valor do campo
                campo.value = (campo.value == "salvar" ? "alterar" : value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Deveria passar o this e mudar dentro da função. Se o ajax falhar? não deve mudar o botão

Comment: @TiagoGomes

pode me auxiliar com um exemplo?

Comment: Vou alterar já posto.

Comment: @Laerte 
uma outra situação é: fazendo desta forma ao atualizar a página o nome do botão volta a ser salvar, e deveria ser alterar.. 
o que acontece, após eu salvar, sempre que recarregar a página os meus options já vem carregados com o valor salvo, mas o botão permanece com o nome salvar.

Comment: Como você sabe que ele alterou o dado? Pois na hora de renderizar com o PHP você pode por essa condição no input.

Comment: Atualizei, caso você me passe qual é o campo que você verifica pra saber se já salvou assim eu altero a resposta.

Comment: @Laerte
fiz o seguinte:

no meu PHP eu adicionei a variável $nomebotao no lugar do value="salvar" do input.
e no onclick eu adicionei o $(this) com parâmetro.

na minha função js eu adicionei o btn como parâmetro do this e as seguinte linha após o sucess do ajax:
 btn.val('Alterar');

Comment: Obrigado! Deu certo aqui.

Comment: Marque como resposta para ajudar os outros. ;)